# How do I recall main using different arguments?

Tags: c

I have my program and it runs like I expected, however, I want to call it again but this time I want to use different arguments. How can I do that?

It seems I cant just use `main(filename1,filename2)`and then follow the same routine I did last before.
My main looks like this

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argc<3)
    {
        printf("Error no filenames\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char* filename=argv[1];
    char* fileout=argv[2];
    int count_Pharmacy;
    int count_Surgicaly;
    int count_General;
    int count_Counselling;
    char pick;

    patient* Pharmacy_head=NULL;
    patient* General_head=NULL;
    patient* Surgical_head=NULL;
    patient* Counselling_head=NULL;
    dep* dep_head=NULL;

    Counselling_head=get_patient(Pharmacy_head,filename,"Counselling");
    Surgical_head=get_patient(Pharmacy_head,filename,"Surgical");
    General_head=get_patient(Pharmacy_head,filename,"General");
    Pharmacy_head=get_patient(Pharmacy_head,filename,"Pharmacy");

    count_Pharmacy=count_patient(Pharmacy_head);
    count_Surgicaly=count_patient(Surgical_head);
    count_General=count_patient(General_head);
    count_Counselling=count_patient(Counselling_head);

    dep_head=make_deparments(dep_head,"Counselling","Dr. Willy",Counselling_head,count_Counselling);
    dep_head=make_deparments(dep_head,"Surgical","Dr. Neo Cortex",Surgical_head,count_Surgicaly);
    dep_head=make_deparments(dep_head,"General","Dr. Ann Imezechara",General_head,count_General);
    dep_head=make_deparments(dep_head,"Pharmacy","Dr. Charles Xavier",Pharmacy_head,count_Pharmacy);
    treatment(dep_head,fileout);
    printf("The patients have been treated would you like to add another file?(Y/N)\n");
    pick=fgetc(stdin);
    if (pick=='y' || pick =='Y')
    {
//this is where i would like to call main again but with diffrent arguments
    }
    else if(pick =='N' || pick=='n')
    {
        printf("Goodbye have a marvelous day\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Thats not a valid input but ill take that as a no\n");
    }


    return 1;
}
```

The two arguments I called main with the first time are file names.

Comment: Done call `main` again. Put the code into a function with a different name and use that instead

Comment: Note that calling `main()` will not reinitialize any global variables. If you want to really start fresh, you should use `execl()` to complately reload the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char * new_argv [4];
int new_argc = 3;

new_argv [0] = argv [0];  // program name
new_argv [1] = "file1";
new_argv [2] = "file2";
new_argv [3] = 0;

main (new_argc, new_argv);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `new_argv[0]` be the name of the process?

Comment: You're violating the guarantee that `argv[argc] == 0` (or `NULL` if you prefer).  You should allocate one more pointer and set that to `0`.

Comment: :-( I had that at one point, but lost it in an edit. Thanks. (Not mobile-ready...)